# Solr returns different result for each letter change

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

When I try searching for products that are having "camel" in their display names. All the indexing procedure have been done. The problem here is:

When I search "camel" I get: 1 product 
 "name": "CHANEL  HYDRA BEAUTY CAMELLIA WATER CREAM  ILLUMINATING HYDRATING FLUID 30ML"

But When I search "CAMELL": I get 3 products from solr:

```
    {
      "name": "CLE DE PEAU Lipstick #5 Camellia"
    },
    {
      "name": "CHANEL  HYDRA BEAUTY CAMELLIA WATER CREAM  ILLUMINATING HYDRATING FLUID 30ML"
    },
    {
      "name": "HERA Rouge Holic Shine No.315 Camellia Orange"
    }
```

When I search CAMEL. I must have got these 3 as well. Why isn't it working?

Comment: can you share tokenizer from your schema.xml for field name

Comment: name is a 'text' type. Here is the tokenizer for text: for index since too long.
`<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
   </analyzer>`

Comment: Here is the remaining half:
`<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
   </analyzer>
  </fieldType>`

Comment: also, share query you are trying q or fq

Comment: In general, if you're using a wildcard in your `q`, the analysis chain will not be invoked. You can add a analyzer chain with the type `multiterm` to try to analyze the query when it's a wildcard as long as you only have filters that are multitermaware. The lowercasefilter should match that description.

Comment: @PrashantThorat Here is the query :
yq=_query_:"\{\!multiMaxScore\+tie%3D0.0\}\(\(brandName_text_en_mv\:camell\^50.0\)\+OR\+\(name_text_en\:camell\^50.0\)\+OR\+\(categoryName_text_en_mv\:camell\^50.0\)\)\+OR\+\(\(brandName_text_en_mv\:camell\~\^25.0\)\+OR\+\(code_string\:camell\~\)\+OR\+\(name_text_en\:camell\~\^25.0\)\+OR\+\(categoryName_text_en_mv\:camell\~\^25.0\)\)\+OR\+\(\(brandName_text_en_mv\:\"camell\"\^100.0\)\+OR\+\(code_string\:\"camell\"\^90.0\)\+OR\+\(name_text_en\:\"camell\"\^100.0\)\+OR\+\(categoryName_text_en_mv\:\"camell\"\^100.0\)\)"

Comment: @MatsLindh Ill try and get back mate

Comment: Start by simplifying your query down to just a `field:query` for a single field and start expanding from that, instead of having a large query with multiple fields. The `multiMaxScore` is also Hybris specific and can be of importantance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed after setting the wildcard flag as true to the indexed properties, in Hybris. Thanks to everyone for your help and ideas.